# Getting 404 onSubmit using React, Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am developing a simple MERN app. I am trying to connect the both ends and post data on server onSubmit(). I am able to access the server URL directly.However, I am getting POST http://localhost:1337/api/register 404 (Not Found) when requesting it from React page.
Any kind of help will be appreciated
Thanks

**server/index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/api/register', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json({status:'ok'})
})

app.listen(1337,() =>{
    console.log('Server started on 1337')
})
```

**client/App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')


  async function registerUser(event){
    event.preventDefault()

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/register',{
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },  
    body:JSON.stringify({
        name,
        email,
        password 
      }),
    })

    const data = await response.json()

    console.log(data)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form onSubmit = {registerUser}>
        <input 
        value = {name}
        onChange = {(e)=> setName(e.target.value)}
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Name"/>
        <br/>
        
        <input 
        value = {email}
        onChange = {(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value)}
        type="email" 
        placeholder="Email"/>
        <br/>
        
        <input 
        value = {password}
        onChange = {(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)}
        type="password" 
        placeholder="Password"/>
        <br/>

        <input type = "submit" value = "Register"/>

      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks

Comment: `app.get('/api/register'` -> `app.post('/api/register'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/api/register', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json({status:'ok'})
})

app.listen(1337,() =>{
    console.log('Server started on 1337')
})
```

**For the post request, we must tell our API requests that it is POST so we must initialize our request with the POST method.**